# Creating Cron job - doubt in crontab in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

In my Zend framework Project I want to create a **Cron Job**. I.e., I want to send a mail to a particular email id (Myname@gmail.com) every 1 hrs. I read many docs. As per I have created a folder named Cron in **Views->script**. I have created a file name **cronresult.php** also I have created its controller page named cronController. But I don't know any further process.

Where I put my php mail function - script to execute at every 1 hrs.
I heard that need to create a crontab, **where I create this Crontab file?**

Also I have one more doubt... When I logged to my cpanel,there is  an option to ceate Cronjobs. SO is it possible to create a cron job from the cpanel?

I don't know any Linux Command.. My project running in CGI

Please help me ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Linux user has his own Cron scheduler to use. You can add jobs with the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

In the text file that open you can schedule scripts to run using the following syntax:

```
0 * * * * php /home/user/example.php
```

This would run the script /home/user/example.php every hour. In the script you can do whatever processing or mailing you need.

Comment: It’s about creating Cronjob from the cpanel? If so in the command textbox I need to type "crontab -e" IS it?

Comment: In cpanel you can follow these steps: http://manual.b2evolution.net/Set_up_a_cpanel_cron_job

Comment: Many many thanks. I want to remember one more thing. Mine is a Zendframework project. So need any additional Changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you edit the crontab, either via cpanel or the shell, the script probably expects to be run by the webserver, not at the command line.

So have your cronjob access the webpage like this:

```
curl --silent --compressed http://my.server.tld/cronresult.php
```